# Javascript string and variable on GET Method , syntax error?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, concatenation, string-concatenation

I want to send a value with get method

`sID` and `rID` are javascript variables. So without using `+` symbol we can not concatenate strings in JS. But the my problem is not only this. if I try like below

assume;

```
var sID = 16;

var rID = 17;
```

---

**EDIT-2:**
Actually string must in open method like this, this is my script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function loadName() {
            var xmlhttp;
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
              $("#btn_add_friend").attr("title", "xxx");
                    document.getElementById("btn_add_friend").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

            };
            var sID = <?php echo $_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"];?>; //value:16
            var rID = <?php echo $profile_owner_id;?>;       //value:17

            xmlhttp.open("GET", "request.php?sender_id=" + sID + "&receiver_id=" + rID, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }

</script>
```

appearing double quotes on browser's address line. I dont want to see double quotes and i want to use sID and rID variables. If I dont use variables script is working but when try to add variables to url it is not working.

format must like that on browser's adress line: `/request.php?sender_id=16&receiver_id=17`

How can I fix it?

Comment: *"...without using `+` symbol we can not concatenate strings in JS"* That's not entirely true. Strings have a `.concat()` method, or you can put them in an Array and use `.join()`.

Comment: I don't see how your code could be inserting quotation marks in the final string. It doesn't when I test your code, and fix the trailing `"`.

Comment: You still need to provide more information. You have an unterminated `"` at the end of your string, and I can't see how this would cause double quotes on the browser's address line.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you have too much `"` there. This should do the work:

```
var url = "request.php?sender_id=" + sID + "&receiver_id=" + rID;
```

**UPDATE**

You have syntax error here:

```
"request.php?sender_id="+sID+"&receiver_id="+rID+"
```

just remove trailing `+"`:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "request.php?sender_id=" + sID + "&receiver_id=" + rID, true);
```

Double quotes won't show up in url because they're used as string delimiter, so everything in between is string (e.g. `"this is my string"`); They won't be a part of actual string (so this will produce desired output).

**UPDATE2**

You forgot to `echo` your php variables:

```
var sID = <?php echo $_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"];?>;
var rID = <?php echo $profile_owner_id;?>;
```

Comment: I don't see the difference. Could you point out what you changed from OP's question? EDIT: ...ah the trailing `"`, though that would be causing a SyntaxError,.

Comment: `"&receiver_id="+rID+"` it looks like hakiko is trying to append `"` at the end of string, which in unnecessary. Though it's a bit of guess, we don't see whole code, so it seems that there must be some double-quote confusion (hint: `syntax error` in title)

Comment: Yeah, that does need to be removed, but it shouldn't cause quotes to appear in the final string. I think we're missing some important info.

Comment: Yes, it does say syntax error in the title, but then OP is also saying that quotation marks are appearing in the address line. I think he's misusing some terms.

Comment: I edit my question. Please check it now. I want to use it for parameter

Comment: Now as OP edited question, we can clearly see that there is syntax error: `+"` at the end of first parameter. Indeed there seems to be some confusion about the double quotes.

Comment: Yeah, +1 because that certainly needs to be fixed. I just can't figure out from the question how OP is getting quotes on the address line.

Comment: Well it seems that there is some misunderstanding (which I've briefly addressed in my answer): double quotes serve as string delimiters and they won't be a part of actual string.

Comment: I edit my question again and I post full script. If I set values(16 and 17) script is working but when I try to add variables sID and rID it is not working:)

Comment: Have you verified that php is returning expected variables? Try: `alert("sId=" + sID); alert("rID=" + rID);` or `console.log(sID, rID);`

Comment: output of alert() is 16 and 17 so values are true. I also add ";" end of var sID and var rID after php tag. now it is sending request but I cant see which url it is trying?